# How can I compare with two strings using if statement?

Tags: java

I tried to make sure if the user entire statement is symmetric or not by trying this code but it's not working how can i compare the last character with the last one ?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("plz enter your string ");
    String UserEntier=s.nextLine();
    int j=UserEntier.length();
    for (int i=0;i<j;i++){
    if (UserEntier.charAt(i)==UserEntier.charAt(j));
    {System.out.println(UserEntier.charAt(i)+UserEntier.charAt(j));j--;}
    else
    System.out.println("not  a symmetric statement");}}
```

Comment: "*but it's not working*" is never good description of problem. How is it not working? Does it not compile? Is it throwing exceptions? Is it returning wrong results? What data did you use?

Comment: What is this syntax: `if {`

Comment: Yes, it is a throwing exception .

Comment: What kind of exception? Should we guess it?

Comment: Comparing String involves "equals()"

Comment: You're not comparing strings, you're comparing `char`s, so `==` will work just fine.  On the other hand, your code is full of simple syntax errors.  Is that what your problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title:

```
String s; // your string
String another; // some other string
if ("someStringValue".equals(s)) {...}
if (another.equals(s)) {...}
if (another.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {...} // compare without casing
```

Note your string should be initialized and contain a value. If you can't guarantee that it isn't null, then you should be passing that value to the argument of the `equals` call.

Also take note of your code formatting:

```
if (/* some boolean */);
{ /* action */; }
```

Your `if` statement will not be tied to any code block, because you end it prematurely with the `;`. You should not put one after the statement itself. As it is right now, `action` will always be executed. An example of what this should look like:

```
if (/* some boolean */) {
    /* action */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its regarding checking whether the entered String is a palindrome or not then its been answered by someone here - [String Symmetry Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258877/string-symmetry-program)